# Looping Through and Printing Nested JSON Object Members

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have successfully returned the object (a store) I was searching for, but now I want to loop through the array of attendants and print the attendants for the store. I cannot use jQuery $each() to iterate. What can I do? Thank you I appreciate your assistance.

totals.js (my service)

```
export const baseUrl = '/src/areas/store-totals/services/tender-total-data.json';
export const all = args =>

  // http.post.standard(baseUrl + 'orders/tenderTotals', {}, args);
  http.get(baseUrl).
  then(function onSuccess(response) { 
    console.log("The response is :" , response);        
  }).
  catch(function onError(response) {
   console.log(response);
  });
```

tender-total-data.json

```
{
  "stores": [
        {
        "storeName": "Master Bistro",
        "storeId": "3046",
        "attendants": [
            {
            "attendantName": "Janis Joplin",
            "attendantId": "9784526",
            "total": 2000,
            "tenderTotal": {
                "Cash": 500,
                "TC": 0,
                "UOD": 500,
                "MC": 250,
                "VI": 250,
                "AX": 250,
                "DI": 250,
                "JC": 0,
                "DC": 0,
                "UOP": 0,
                "GN": 0,
                "UOGC": 0,
                "HOTEL": 0,
                "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            },
            {
            "attendantName": "David Bowie",
            "attendantId": "2589456",
            "total": 14675,
            "tenderTotal": {
                "Cash": 175,
                "TC": 0,
                "UOD": 100,
                "MC": 9500,
                "VI": 3500,
                "AX": 550,
                "DI": 850,
                "JC": 0,
                "DC": 0,
                "UOP": 0,
                "GN": 0,
                "UOGC": 0,
                "HOTEL": 0,
                "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            },
            {
            "attendantName": "Michael Jackson",
            "attendantId": "5478264",
            "total": 15599,
                "tenderTotal": {
                    "Cash": 250,
                    "TC": 0,
                    "UOD": 80,
                    "MC": 5624,
                    "VI": 6895,
                    "AX": 2500,
                    "DI": 250,
                    "JC": 0,
                    "DC": 0,
                    "UOP": 0,
                    "GN": 0,
                    "UOGC": 0,
                    "HOTEL": 0,
                    "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            }
        ],
            "message": "Store totals for 08/20/2018",
            "date":"08/20/2018"
    },{

        "storeName": "The Master  Marketplace",
        "storeId": "3047",
        "attendants": [
            {
                "attendantName": "Dirk Novitski",
                "attendantId": "9784527",
                "total": 2000,
                "tenderTotal": {
                    "Cash": 500,
                    "TC": 0,
                    "UOD": 500,
                    "MC": 250,
                    "VI": 250,
                    "AX": 250,
                    "DI": 250,
                    "JC": 0,
                    "DC": 0,
                    "UOP": 0,
                    "GN": 0,
                    "UOGC": 0,
                    "HOTEL": 0,
                    "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "attendantName": "Carmello Anthony",
                "attendantId": "2589458",
                "total": 14675,
                "tenderTotal": {
                    "Cash": 175,
                    "TC": 0,
                    "UOD": 100,
                    "MC": 9500,
                    "VI": 3500,
                    "AX": 550,
                    "DI": 850,
                    "JC": 0,
                    "DC": 0,
                    "UOP": 0,
                    "GN": 0,
                    "UOGC": 0,
                    "HOTEL": 0,
                    "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "attendantName": "Stevie Wonder",
                "attendantId": "5478266",
                "total": 15599,
                "tenderTotal": {
                    "Cash": 250,
                    "TC": 0,
                    "UOD": 80,
                    "MC": 5624,
                    "VI": 6895,
                    "AX": 2500,
                    "DI": 250,
                    "JC": 0,
                    "DC": 0,
                    "UOP": 0,
                    "GN": 0,
                    "UOGC": 0,
                    "HOTEL": 0,
                    "NCTNCG": 0
                }

            }
        ],
            "message": "Store totals for 08/22/2018",
            "date":"08/21/2018"
        }
    ]    
}
```

Comment: You can use for `.forEach` function on the array, which is very similar to jquery's `each`. Just do `arr.forEach((item) => { console.log(item) });` where `arr` is the array you want to loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the attandants for the particular store, you can use array.find as follows,

```js
let data ={
  "stores": [
    {
      "storeName": "Master Bistro",
      "storeId": "3046",
      "attendants": [
        {
          "attendantName": "Janis Joplin",
          "attendantId": "9784526",
          "total": 2000,
          "tenderTotal": {
            "Cash": 500,
            "TC": 0,
            "UOD": 500,
            "MC": 250,
            "VI": 250,
            "AX": 250,
            "DI": 250,
            "JC": 0,
            "DC": 0,
            "UOP": 0,
            "GN": 0,
            "UOGC": 0,
            "HOTEL": 0,
            "NCTNCG": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "attendantName": "David Bowie",
          "attendantId": "2589456",
          "total": 14675,
          "tenderTotal": {
            "Cash": 175,
            "TC": 0,
            "UOD": 100,
            "MC": 9500,
            "VI": 3500,
            "AX": 550,
            "DI": 850,
            "JC": 0,
            "DC": 0,
            "UOP": 0,
            "GN": 0,
            "UOGC": 0,
            "HOTEL": 0,
            "NCTNCG": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "attendantName": "Michael Jackson",
          "attendantId": "5478264",
          "total": 15599,
          "tenderTotal": {
            "Cash": 250,
            "TC": 0,
            "UOD": 80,
            "MC": 5624,
            "VI": 6895,
            "AX": 2500,
            "DI": 250,
            "JC": 0,
            "DC": 0,
            "UOP": 0,
            "GN": 0,
            "UOGC": 0,
            "HOTEL": 0,
            "NCTNCG": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "message": "Store totals for 08/20/2018",
      "date": "08/20/2018"
    },
    {
      "storeName": "The Master  Marketplace",
      "storeId": "3047",
      "attendants": [
        {
          "attendantName": "Dirk Novitski",
          "attendantId": "9784527",
          "total": 2000,
          "tenderTotal": {
            "Cash": 500,
            "TC": 0,
            "UOD": 500,
            "MC": 250,
            "VI": 250,
            "AX": 250,
            "DI": 250,
            "JC": 0,
            "DC": 0,
            "UOP": 0,
            "GN": 0,
            "UOGC": 0,
            "HOTEL": 0,
            "NCTNCG": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "attendantName": "Carmello Anthony",
          "attendantId": "2589458",
          "total": 14675,
          "tenderTotal": {
            "Cash": 175,
            "TC": 0,
            "UOD": 100,
            "MC": 9500,
            "VI": 3500,
            "AX": 550,
            "DI": 850,
            "JC": 0,
            "DC": 0,
            "UOP": 0,
            "GN": 0,
            "UOGC": 0,
            "HOTEL": 0,
            "NCTNCG": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "attendantName": "Stevie Wonder",
          "attendantId": "5478266",
          "total": 15599,
          "tenderTotal": {
            "Cash": 250,
            "TC": 0,
            "UOD": 80,
            "MC": 5624,
            "VI": 6895,
            "AX": 2500,
            "DI": 250,
            "JC": 0,
            "DC": 0,
            "UOP": 0,
            "GN": 0,
            "UOGC": 0,
            "HOTEL": 0,
            "NCTNCG": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "message": "Store totals for 08/22/2018",
      "date": "08/21/2018"
    }
  ]
};

let attendants = data.stores.find(store=>store.storeId == 3047).attendants;
 
attendants.forEach( (element) => {
  console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate the array elements you can use functions such as map or forEach. If you use map, the iterating logic would be something similar to :

```
attendants.map((item) => {
 console.log(item);
});
```